# why is a nod within an array considered 'nod' instead of 'struct nod'?

Tags: c, arrays

I am currently trying to implement the algorithm Radix Sort. In order to implemented I have to create an array of linked lists. I do this in the following lines:

```
typedef struct _nod {
    struct _nod *next;
    int val;
}   nod;
v=(nod*)malloc(10*sizeof(nod));
```

I feed the following function an unsorted linked list (v), an 'n' which represents the digit that I want to return(1 means that I want the unit number, 10 means that I want the tens digit number and so on) and an unsorted linked list (cap) which must be sorted.

```
nod *sorteaza(nod *v,nod *cap,int n)    {
    nod *sort,*aux;
    int cat,r,i;
    sort=(nod*)malloc(sizeof(nod));
    while(cap->next!=NULL)  {
        cat=cap->val/n;
        r=cat%10;
        adaugaSfarsit(&v[r],cap->val);
        cap=cap->next;
    }
    cat=cap->val/n;
    r=cat%10;
    adaugaSfarsit((nod)v[r],cap->val);

    for(i=0;i<10;i++)   {
        aux=&v[i];
        while(aux->next!=NULL)  {
            adaugaSfarsitNod(sort,v[i].next);
            aux=aux->next;
        }
        adaugaSfarsitNod(sort,v[i].next);

    }
}
```

The problem I am facing when I run this program is being generated by v[i] which gives me the following error:

```
1.c: In function ‘sorteaza’:
1.c:73:2: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘adaugaSfarsit’
  adaugaSfarsit((nod)v[r],cap->val);
  ^
1.c:29:6: note: expected ‘struct nod *’ but argument is of type ‘nod’
 nod* adaugaSfarsit (nod *cap,int inf)
```

Can anyone explain to me why it gives me this error? As far as I know v[i] is a nod and that's what I request in the parameters of adaugaSfarsit which is declared like this:

```
nod* adaugaSfarsit (nod *cap,int inf)

{
    nod *nou, *p;
    p = cap;
    nou = (nod*) malloc( sizeof(nod));
    nou->val=inf;
    nou->next = NULL;
    if(cap == NULL)
        cap=nou;
    while (cap->next != NULL)
        cap = cap->next;    //parcurg lista pana ajung la ultimul nod
    cap->next = nou;    //adaug elementul
    return p;
}


nod* adaugaSfarsitNod (nod *cap,nod *nou)

{
    nod *p;
    p = cap;
    if(cap == NULL)
        cap=nou;
    while (cap->next != NULL)
        cap = cap->next;    //parcurg lista pana ajung la ultimul nod
    cap->next = nou;    //adaug elementul
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Because you have `typedef`ed it (question title).

Comment: `nod` and `nod*` are not the same.

Comment: Probably instead of `(nod)v[r]` you need `&v[r]` or `v+r`

Answer (score 3):

You have too many casts, it might indicate that you are fighting with the compiler and forcing it to accept your code, which is very bad.

The problem is

```
adaugaSfarsit((nod)v[r],cap->val);
              /* ^ here it's very wrong */
```

not only `v[r]` is already of type `nod` but also, you are casting it to `nod`?

So the solution is to change it with this

```
adaugaSfarsit(&v[r], cap->val);
```

Comment: Nice 'fighting with the compiler' is no good (no clue if the answer is correct)